A machine learning model for predicting bit strings in Java
I have this GitHub repository (BitPredictor.java). Basically, I tried to harness a machine learning model for predicting bit strings. I have implemented it to the best of my understanding and have compared it to a very trivial ML-model, yet my demo program shows that it could have been better.
Note here that my code compiles and does not throw exceptions. However, the statistical performance requires improvement. Below are my main classes implemnting the bit string prediction:
com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.impl.MachineLearningBitPredictor.java:
package com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.BitPredictor;
import com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util.BitStringView;
import com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util.BitFrequencyDistribution;
import static com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util.Utils.checkIsPositiveValue;
import com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util.BitStringTree;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements a machine learning approach to predicting the bit 
 * strings.
 */
public final class MachineLearningBitPredictor implements BitPredictor {
    
    private static final int MAXIMUM_PATTERN_LENGTH_UPPER_BOUND = 26;
    private static final int DEFAULT_PATTERN_LENGTH_UPPER_BOUND = 10;

    private final boolean[] bits;
    private final int maximumPatternLength;
    private final Random random;
    private final BitStringTree bitStringTree = new BitStringTree();

    public MachineLearningBitPredictor(final boolean[] bits, 
                                       final int maximumPatternLength,
                                       final Random random) {
        
        this.bits = Objects.requireNonNull(bits, "The input bits is null.");
        this.maximumPatternLength = 
                checkMaximumPatternLength(maximumPatternLength);
        
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random,
                                             "The input Random is null.");
        learnModel();
    }
    
    public MachineLearningBitPredictor(final boolean[] bits, 
                                       final Random random) {
        this(bits, DEFAULT_PATTERN_LENGTH_UPPER_BOUND, random);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean predict(final BitStringView bitStringView) {
        // Start from the largest pattern lengths:
        for (int patternLength = maximumPatternLength; 
                 patternLength >= 0; 
                 patternLength--) {
            
            if (patternLength > bitStringView.length()) {
                // Once here, the current pattern is longer than the input bit
                // string view, omit:
                continue;
            }
            
            // Get the patternLength long pattern suffix:
            final BitStringView patternSuffixView = 
                    getPatternSuffix(bitStringView, patternLength);
            
            patternSuffixView.contractFromTail(bits.length);
            
            // Grab the bit frequencies:
            final BitFrequencyDistribution bitFrequencies = 
                    bitStringTree.get(patternSuffixView);
            
            if (bitFrequencies != null) {
                // Sample the bit:
                return bitFrequencies.sample(random);
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean[] predictArray(final int length) {
        checkIsPositiveValue(
                length,
                String.format(
                        "The length is too small (%d). Must be at least 1.",
                        length));
        
        final boolean[] predictedArray = new boolean[length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            final BitStringView bitStringView =
                    new BitStringView(
                            bits,
                            i,
                            maximumPatternLength);
            
            predictedArray[i] = predict(bitStringView);
        }
        
        return predictedArray;
    }
    
    private BitStringView getPatternSuffix(final BitStringView pattern, 
                                           final int suffixLength) {
        
        return new BitStringView(
                bits, 
                pattern.getStartIndex() + pattern.length() - suffixLength, 
                suffixLength);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return bitStringTree.toString();
    }
    
    private int checkMaximumPatternLength(final int maximumPatternLength) {
        if (maximumPatternLength < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "Maximum pattern length is too small (%d), " + 
                                    "must be at least 1.", 
                            maximumPatternLength));
        }
        
        return Math.min(maximumPatternLength, 
                        Math.min(MAXIMUM_PATTERN_LENGTH_UPPER_BOUND,
                                 bits.length - 1));
    }
    
    private void learnModel() {
        for (int patternLength = 0; 
                 patternLength <= maximumPatternLength; 
                 patternLength++) {
            
            learnModelForPatternLength(patternLength);
        }
    }
    
    private void learnModelForPatternLength(final int patternLength) {
        for (int patternStartIndex = 0; 
                 patternStartIndex < bits.length - patternLength; 
                 patternStartIndex++) {
            
            loadPattern(patternStartIndex, 
                        patternLength);
        }
    }
    
    private void loadPattern(final int patternStartIndex, 
                             final int patternLength) {
        
        final BitStringView pattern = 
                new BitStringView(
                        bits, 
                        patternStartIndex, 
                        patternLength);
        
        final boolean bitToPredict = bits[patternStartIndex + patternLength];
        final BitFrequencyDistribution bitFrequencies =
                bitStringTree.get(pattern);
        
        if (bitFrequencies != null) {
            if (bitToPredict) {
                bitFrequencies.incrementOneBitCounter();
            } else {
                bitFrequencies.incrementZeroBitCounter();
            }
        } else {
            bitStringTree.add(pattern, bitToPredict);
        }
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util.BitStringTree.java:
package com.github.coderodde.fun.bits.predictor.util;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.List;

public final class BitStringTree {
    
    private static final class BitStringTreeNode {
        BitStringTreeNode bit0Child;
        BitStringTreeNode bit1Child;
        BitFrequencyDistribution bitFrequencies;
        
        BitStringTreeNode() {
            this.bitFrequencies = new BitFrequencyDistribution();
        }
    }
    
    private final BitStringTreeNode root = new BitStringTreeNode();
    private int size = 1; // Count the root.
     
    public void add(final BitStringView bitStringView, 
                    final boolean predictedBit) {
        
        BitStringTreeNode current = root;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bitStringView.length(); i++) {
            final boolean bit = bitStringView.get(i);
            
            if (bit) {
                if (current.bit1Child == null) {
                    current.bit1Child = new BitStringTreeNode();
                    size++;
                }
                
                current.bitFrequencies.incrementOneBitCounter();
                current = current.bit1Child;
            } else {
                if (current.bit0Child == null) {
                    current.bit0Child = new BitStringTreeNode();
                    size++;
                }
                
                current.bitFrequencies.incrementZeroBitCounter();
                current = current.bit0Child;
            }    
        }
        
        if (predictedBit) {
            current.bitFrequencies.incrementOneBitCounter();
        } else {
            current.bitFrequencies.incrementZeroBitCounter();
        }
    }
    
    public BitFrequencyDistribution get(final BitStringView bitStringView) {
        BitStringTreeNode node = root;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bitStringView.length(); i++) {
            final boolean bit = bitStringView.get(i);
            
            if (bit) {
                if (node.bit1Child == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                
                node = node.bit1Child;
            } else {
                if (node.bit0Child == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                
                node = node.bit0Child;
            }
        }
        
        return node.bitFrequencies;
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final List<TextLine> textLineList = getTextLines();
        
        final int maximumPatternStringLength = 
                getMaximumPatternStringLength(textLineList);
        
        final int maximum0bitCountStringLength = 
                getMaximum0bitCountStringLength(textLineList);
        
        final int maximum1bitCountStringLength = 
                getMaximum1bitCountStringLength(textLineList);
        
        final int maximumLineNumberStringLength =
                Integer.toString(size).length();
        
        final String formatString = 
                "Pattern %%%dd: \"%%%ds\", ones = %%%dd, zeros = %%%dd\n";
        
        final String formatString2 =
                String.format(
                        formatString,
                        maximumLineNumberStringLength,
                        maximumPatternStringLength,
                        maximum1bitCountStringLength, 
                        maximum0bitCountStringLength);
        
        Collections.sort(textLineList);
        
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        int lineNumber = 1;
        
        for (final TextLine textLine : textLineList) {
            stringBuilder.append(
                    String.format(
                            formatString2, 
                            lineNumber++, 
                            textLine.patternString,
                            textLine.bitFrequencies.bit[1],
                            textLine.bitFrequencies.bit[0]));
        }
        
        // Delete the last "\n" string:
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    private int getMaximumPatternStringLength(
            final List<TextLine> textLineList) {
        
        int tentativeMaximum = 0;
        
        for (final TextLine textLine : textLineList) {
            tentativeMaximum = Math.max(tentativeMaximum, 
                                        textLine.patternString.length());
        }
        
        return tentativeMaximum;
    }
    
    private int getMaximum0bitCountStringLength(
            final List<TextLine> textLineList) {
        
        int tentativeMaximum = 0;
        
        for (final TextLine textLine : textLineList) {
            tentativeMaximum = 
                    Math.max(tentativeMaximum, 
                             textLine.get0BitFrequencyNumberLength());
        }
        
        return tentativeMaximum;
    }
    
    private int getMaximum1bitCountStringLength(
            final List<TextLine> textLineList) {
        
        int tentativeMaximum = 0;
        
        for (final TextLine textLine : textLineList) {
            tentativeMaximum = 
                    Math.max(tentativeMaximum, 
                             textLine.get1BitFrequencyNumberLength());
        }
        
        return tentativeMaximum;
    }
    
    private List<TextLine> getTextLines() {
        List<TextLine> textLineList = new ArrayList<>(size);
        
        getTextLinesImpl(textLineList,
                         new ArrayDeque<>(),
                         root);
        
        return textLineList;
    }
    
    private void getTextLinesImpl(final List<TextLine> textLineList, 
                                  final Deque<Boolean> nodePath,
                                  final BitStringTreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            // End the recursion.
            return;
        }
        
        // Construct current text line:
        final TextLine textLine = new TextLine(nodePath,
                                               root.bitFrequencies);
        
        // Descend to the left subtree:
        nodePath.addLast(Boolean.FALSE);
        getTextLinesImpl(textLineList, nodePath, root.bit0Child);
        nodePath.removeLast();
        
        // Store the current text line:
        textLineList.add(textLine);
        
        // Descend to the right subtree:
        nodePath.addLast(Boolean.TRUE);
        getTextLinesImpl(textLineList, nodePath, root.bit1Child);
        nodePath.removeLast();
    }
    
    private static final class TextLine implements Comparable<TextLine> {
        private final int patternNumber;
        private final String patternString;
        private final BitFrequencyDistribution bitFrequencies;
        
        TextLine(final Deque<Boolean> bitPattern, 
                 final BitFrequencyDistribution bitFrequencies) {
            
            this.patternNumber  = getPatternValue(bitPattern);
            this.patternString  = convertPatternToString(bitPattern);
            this.bitFrequencies = bitFrequencies;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            
            stringBuilder.append("[TextLine | pattern value = ")
                         .append(patternNumber)
                         .append(" | bit pattern = ")
                         .append(patternString)
                         .append(" | bit freqs = ")
                         .append(bitFrequencies)
                         .append("]");
            
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        
        String convertPatternToString(final Deque<Boolean> bitPattern) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            
            for (final Boolean bit : bitPattern) {
                stringBuilder.append((bit ? "1" : "0"));
            }
            
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        
        int get1BitFrequencyNumberLength() {
            return String.valueOf(bitFrequencies.bit[1]).length();
        }
        
        int get0BitFrequencyNumberLength() {
            return String.valueOf(bitFrequencies.bit[0]).length();
        }
        
        @Override
        public int compareTo(final TextLine o) {
            return patternString.compareTo(o.patternString);
        }
        
        private static int getPatternValue(final Deque<Boolean> bitPattern) {
            int value = 0;
            
            for (final boolean bit : bitPattern) {
                value <<= 1;
                
                if (bit) {
                    value |= 0b1;
                }
            }
            
            return  value;
        }
    }
}

Typical demo output
--- Pattern length: 1, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 1, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 100, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  100,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 200, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  100,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 100,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 2, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 400, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  66,67 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 3, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  75,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 75,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 400, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 25,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 4, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 75,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 200, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  40,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 20,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  20,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  20,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 20,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 700, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  80,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 900, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  40,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 20,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 5, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 100, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 16,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 500, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  66,67 %.
Similarity MLBP: 16,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 600, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  83,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 700, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  83,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 900, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 6, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  14,29 %.
Similarity MLBP: 14,29 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 200, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  57,14 %.
Similarity MLBP: 42,86 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  28,57 %.
Similarity MLBP: 42,86 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 400, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 14,29 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 500, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 14,29 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 57,14 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 42,86 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 57,14 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  42,86 %.
Similarity MLBP: 42,86 %.

--- Pattern length: 7, length = 1000, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  28,57 %.
Similarity MLBP: 14,29 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  37,50 %.
Similarity MLBP: 62,50 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 200, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  37,50 %.
Similarity MLBP: 12,50 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  12,50 %.
Similarity MLBP: 25,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 62,50 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 700, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  25,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 25,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  37,50 %.
Similarity MLBP: 62,50 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 8, length = 1000, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  62,50 %.
Similarity MLBP: 50,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 100, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  22,22 %.
Similarity MLBP: 44,44 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  44,44 %.
Similarity MLBP: 55,56 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 300, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  33,33 %.
Similarity MLBP: 44,44 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  22,22 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 500, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  77,78 %.
Similarity MLBP: 66,67 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  22,22 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 700, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  66,67 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 800, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  66,67 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 900, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  55,56 %.
Similarity MLBP: 33,33 %.

--- Pattern length: 9, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  0,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 0,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 100, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  60,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 200, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  20,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 20,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 300, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  70,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 60,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 400, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  40,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 500, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 60,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 600, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  30,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 30,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 700, improved = false
Similarity FBP:  60,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 800, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  50,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 60,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 900, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  10,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 30,00 %.

--- Pattern length: 10, length = 1000, improved = true
Similarity FBP:  30,00 %.
Similarity MLBP: 40,00 %.

Improved: 75, run: 100, ratio: 0,750.

Critique request
This time, I would like to hear not only comments on coding stylistic issues such as naming, indentation and overall code layout, but also comments on how to improve my prediction statistics.

For ML illiterates, what would be a desired output?

@vnp In my opinion, whatever works bettern than a naïve predictor that simply samples each next bit via an uniform distribution.
